# How to display Delete-Form as button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I try to display a delete-button as a bootstrap button. The problem is, that my delete Button is included in a form tag with other hidden-elements. Therefore the button is displayed in a new row. So how can I display this button in the same row as the others?

```
<a href="/carpool/{{ $carpool->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Anzeigen</a>
<a href="/carpool/{{ $carpool->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Bearbeiten</a>
<span class="form-inline">
  <form method="post" action="{{ route('carpool.destroy', [$carpool->id]) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Entfernen</button>
  </form>
</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show Your Code Please .

Comment: *Therefore the button is displayed in a new row. So how to do that?* What To Do.? Question Is Unclear. Please Elaborate..

Answer (score 1):

Move your other anchor tags inside `form` and use `form-inline` class in `form` tag. All your buttons will be show in a single line.

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline" action="{{ route('carpool.destroy', [$carpool->id]) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <a href="/carpool/{{ $carpool->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Anzeigen</a>
    <a href="/carpool/{{ $carpool->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Bearbeiten</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Entfernen</button>
</form>
```